# How can I read this nested json in php?

Tags: php, json

I have this JSON

```
{
"AED_USD": {
"2019-08-01": 0.272242
}
}
```

When dumping this as an array I have:

```
array(1) { ["AED_USD"]=> array(1) { ["2019-08-01"]=> float(0.272242) } }
```

I am trying to reach get the float value of 0.272242.

How do I get this value in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `json_decode` the string with `true` as second parameter to make it an array, and then just echo what you want using the name of the keys you have. Like so:

```
$string = '{
    "AED_USD": {
        "2019-08-01": 0.272242
    }
}';

$decode = json_decode($string, true);

echo $decode['AED_USD']['2019-08-01'];
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the value in PHP, you can do

```
$value = $yourArray['AED_USD']['2019-08-01'];
```

If you want more information: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php